# Get file name and pass it to another function in Python

Tags: python

I got this code, that looks on a directory for .rar files and unrar them to another directory. I want to be able to fetch the name of the file that has been unrared for the purpose to change to the destination directory ( wich is the file minus the extension ) and from there do more work, but I can't do anything else after the `if` ( like, getting te file name with `os.path.basename()` before executing  `patoolib.extract_archive(my_file, outdir="/root/tree/def")`

How can I get the file name and pass that to another function ?

The code:

```
import shutil, os, patoolib, fnmatch, glob

def unrar():
    for my_file in glob.glob('/root/tree/down/*'):
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(my_file, '*.rar'):
            patoolib.extract_archive(
                my_file, outdir="/root/tree/def")

unrar()
```

Comment: you can try for f in os.listdir(DIRECTORY_NAME):
         if file_n.endswith('.rar'):

Answer (score 0):

you can try the following code to get the .rar file one-by-one :

```
import os
for f in os.listdir(<dir_name>):
     if f.endswith('.rar'):
         print file
         #do your stuff
         patoolib.extract_archive(file, outdir="/root/tree/def")
```

here's an example.

consider the following folder /Users/bla/xyz with the following contents

```
a.rar
b.rar
c.txt
```

if you apply the code above on this folder, you'll get only the far files without extension :

```
a.rar
b.rar
```

now you can pass those files to whatever function you want...

Comment: What I want to do is to get the file name that has been processed and pass it to another function so I can do more things with it.

Comment: what do you mean "the file name that has been processed" ? isn't it the rar file itself ?

Comment: I want to get the name of the rar  file that i am processing  minus the extension , and pass it to another function to work with it.

Comment: @xavier, this is exactly what my code does, please see the example i've added.